# Multi dimensional table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to have a multi-dimensional table in mySQL

I want to log users based on based on their ip, their user-agent and the session token they sent.

Something like this:

```
ip1
    user-agent1
        session token1
    user-agent2
        session token2
        session token3
ip2
    user-agent3
        session token4
```

I would like to avoid using `serialize()` as I've heard it would make the table less efficient and less portable.

Comment: This kind of thing is normally handled with multiple tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that you have a multi-dimensional table, but rather *multiple tables*.

#### Table ips

```
id INT
ip VARCHAR
```

#### Table useragents (links UA to IP)

```
ip_id INT
useragent VARCHAR(2048) (some large value)
```

#### Table tokens (links users to tokens)

```
id
userid 
token
```

All three of the components above are linked together via their `id` columns into a table identifying sessions. Multiple `ip_id` may associate with a single `token`, which in turn associates multiple possible UA strings.

It leaves the possibility that there can be identical UA strings for the same IP, but with multiple different session tokens from that same IP.

#### Table sessions

```
ip_id
token_id
```